# Объясните, как работает упаковка бит в переменную для N > 2 чисел

Tags: c, алгоритм, битовые-операции, байты

Помогите адаптировать данную упаковку бит под N-ое количество входных чисел. Я нашел [здесь](https://coderoad.ru/3499444/%D0%A1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) пример того, как упаковать два числа в переменную большего размера. Как это работает для двух чисел вроде бы понятно. Давайте разберем на примере с числами 256 и 260. Сначала код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
     
int getBitSize(int code)
{
    return ceil(log2(code + 1));
}

unsigned long compressBits(int a, int b)
{
    int sizeA = getBitSize(a);
    unsigned long compressed = (a << sizeA) | b;
    return  compressed;
}

unsigned int* decompressBits(unsigned long compressedBits)
{
    unsigned int num1 = (compressedBits & 0b111111111000000000) >> 9;
    unsigned int num2 = (compressedBits & 0b000000000111111111);
    unsigned int* numArr = checkNull(malloc(2 * sizeof(unsigned int)));
    numArr[0] = num1;
    numArr[1] = num2;
    return numArr;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long cBits = compressBits(256, 260);
    unsigned int * dBits = decompressBits(cBits);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d number = %d\n", i + 1, dBits[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Итак, что происходит в упаковке:

```
  1. Получаем на вход 2 числа : 256 (0000000100000000) и 260 (0000000100000100)
  2. Вычисляем во сколько бит можно уместить первое число (в 9)
  3. Сдвигаем влево первое число на 9 бит (0000000100000000 << 9 = 10000000000000000)
  4. Применяем побитовое ИЛИ к результату пункта 3 (1000000000000000 | 0000000100000100 = 100000000100000100) = 131332
```

Распаковка

```
  1. Получаем наши запакованные числа (100000000100000100)
  2. Применяем к ним битовое И с маской (100000000100000100 & 1111111110 = 1000000001000000)
  3. Сдвигаем вправо полученное число на 9 бит (1000000001000000 >> 9 = 0000000100000000 = 256 (Первое исходное число))
  4. Читаем оставшиеся биты числа (100000000100000100 & 0000000001111111110 = 0000000001000100 = 260 (Второе исходное число))
```

Я хочу упаковать в unsigned long больше чисел по 9 бит (в теории можно до 6-ти), но не пойму как это сделать. Помогите усовершенствовать алгоритм.

Comment: В теории размер `unsigned long` не определен :) На практике это 4 байта == 32 бита, то есть максимум 3 9-битных числа...

Comment: @Harry Действительно, я почему-то был уверен, что  unsigned  Long  = 64 бита... Но не суть, запаковать 3 у меня тоже не получилось. А для большего количества, думаю, можно будет выделить массив long-ов.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, ну так 8 байтный `unsigned long` на практике тоже не редкость :) [gcc](https://ideone.com/HCUOyq), [clang](https://ideone.com/HeLdYC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да вот, примерно так:

```
unsigned int get9(unsigned int val, unsigned int no)
{
    const unsigned int mask = 0x1FF;
    return (val >> no*9)&mask;
}

unsigned int set9(unsigned int val, unsigned int no, unsigned int to_val)
{
    const unsigned int mask = 0x1FF;
    to_val = (to_val&mask)<< (no*9);
    return (val & ~(mask << no*9))| to_val;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int val = 0;
    val = set9(val,0,260);
    val = set9(val,1,270);
    val = set9(val,2,280);

    printf("%u - %u - %u\n",get9(val,0),get9(val,1),get9(val,2));
}
```

Просто используем битовые операции для записи в соответствующие девятки...